# "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google" on checking for undefined

Tags: javascript, ios, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, cordova

I thought I had Javascript pretty much figured out, then this (seemingly basic) thing pops up:

I have a Phonegap / jQuery Mobile app that uses Google Maps. If the phone's internet connection is unavailable briefly, and at the exact time the app was trying to load the Google Maps API upon app start-up, all maps related functionality naturally won't work.

However, the weird thing is this code causes the function it's in to break and stop executing past the if check (meaning the `doSomething()` line never executes):

```
function myFunction() {
    if(google === undefined) {
        alert("Google Maps didn't load!");
    }

    doSomething();
}
```

When looking at the console in Safari's developer tools I see the error in this post's title.

Aren't checks for undefined variables like this supposed to be safe? I want to handle this edge case where the Google Maps API isn't loaded, but how can I do that if I can't check for undefined? I tried just doing `if(!google)`, but that gave the same result.

I've also tried using he Google Loader to load the maps API dynamically when the user navigates to a page using maps, but I haven't been able to get that to work (Loader would have to be dynamically loaded as well for this to be of help, and I can't seem to be able to dynamically load any script). I tried doing it dynamically with pure Javascript as well, but I think the `document.write` in the Google Maps API Javascript is breaking that on Mobile Safari. I also tried using jQuery's `$.getScript()`without success.

In any case, I should be able to handle this edge case if I can detect that the maps API hasn't been loaded, so it all boils down to: How can that be done, and why doesn't the above undefined check work?

Comment: Try `if (typeof google === "undefined") {`

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I'm gonna blame the late Friday afternoon for neglecting to think of this. I used to use the typeof operator quite a bit, but JSLint and other programmers complained all the time, so I just completely stopped using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
function myFunction() {
    if(window.google === undefined) {
        alert("Google Maps didn't load!");
    }

    doSomething();
}
```

That's because `google` is interpreted as a non-declared identifier, whereas `window.google` is a property of `window` that might be `undefined` or not.

### EDIT:

You can also use `!window.google`, since `google` is an object and thus cannot be `null`, `undefined`, `0` nor other falsy values.

Comment: Thanks, this worked (will accept as soon as I'm allowed to by the system). Ian's suggestion in his comment also worked. So: It appears that when testing an identifier one should use `typeof`, and when testing an object property one can test directly against `undefined` - at least in Mobile Safari.

Comment: @JoeDyndale Well, it's all up to the programmer. You can test against `undefined`, but `undefined` technically isn't a reserved word and *could* be set as something else, breaking comparisons (probably something you shouldn't worry about). Using `typeof` is guaranteed to yield the result you need. The way you should test for **existence** of object properties is with `in` (or `hasOwnProperty`), such as `if ("google" in window)`. Technically, you could just use `if (window.google)`. I just like to stick with something that works in every scenario - `typeof`

Comment: I've had many cases where `typeof === "undefined"` has not worked, which is why I stopped using it. I was told that `myVar === undefined` was the most reliable test. And yeah, I always use `for..in` and `hasOwnProperty` to test for the existence of a property.

Comment: @JoeDyndale Can you provide an example? I've never seen it fail. I know it can say the "wrong" thing in IE - for example, `typeof console.log` (when Developer Tools is open) is "object", not "function".

Comment: I can't remember at the moment, as it's so long since I've used `typeof`, but as far as I can recall the only times it didn't work, at least not anywhere near reliably, was with `typeof someVar === "undefined"`.

Comment: I think this answer is most acceptable as far as handling an object in `JS` is concern.

Comment: That does not answer why/how the error happens. I'm initialising google maps as providied and still got this error sometimes.